# 15 minute gap between end of Rest Controller method and Controller Advice

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm facing a pretty serious issue after deploying my application to a new environment. The application itself is a Spring Boot REST API service. After my REST controller method exits, it is supposed to proceed to a Controller Advice class where I do some post-processing (using the @ControllerAdvice annotation). However, from the logs, I saw that about 5% of requests are timing out and investigations revealed that there is a 15 minute gap between the end of the Controller method and the Controller Advice:

[image: Illustration of Timeout]

Logs 1-5 belong to the Controller method. After that, you will see an exception from Zuul timing out after waiting for 30 seconds. And then, 15 minutes later, you will see that the logs for this particular thread start running again, which are for the Controller Advice.

I'm really running out of ideas on why this is happening. The gap seems to be a very consistent 15 minutes (give or take 10-15 seconds). Would anybody have had similar experience or know what may be happening given the architecture of Spring / Boot?

Comment: I don't see how we could even really start helping to debug without some code. [mcve]

Comment: Is it 15 seconds or 15 minutes? Your title says 15 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, it's 15 minutes. Will fix.

Comment: how about taking a thread dump?

Comment: Yes, we took a thread dump and eventually found the issue (it was a hung DB socket read in the end). But simulating the issue consistently was difficult and I thought I'd ask for some clues here in the meantime. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of timeouts:

- The connection timeout, before you establish a socket
- The read timeout, once the dialog is in progress

I think you are hitting the read timeout here. You can test this theory by creating a JUnit integration test with a RestClient and change the timeout parameters. The test's behavior might reveal the issue.

```
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(5000);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```